# C++Pointer to a Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a question about pointer to class.I mean In the Offering class i wanted to create a `Course * sample` pointer ,by the way course is also another class which takes one int argument , and than tried to take space from memory via `sample=new Course;` but i got an error which says:

```
Offering.cpp:12:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘Course::Course()’
Offering.cpp:12:19: note: candidates are:
lib.h:63:5: note: Course::Course(int)
lib.h:63:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Is there anyone who knows where am i wrong ? thanks anyway.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to help. But have you read the error message and what it's trying to tell you? The fix is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Write `Course *sample = new Course(11);`

If course takes an `int` as constructor parameter, you have to pass it, even when allocation on heap.

Answer (score 0):

Define a default constructor for `Course`.  If you can't, or shouldn't, you'll have to use an existing one.

```
Course * sample = new Course(1337);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
Course *sample = new Course(10);
```

It is because you apparently defined a Constructor for Course which is defined as:

```
Course(int);
```

The default constructor ( Course() ) will not be added automatically when you define a custom one.